# Including a somewhat large C library in Cython

Tags: python, c, cython

I'm very new to Cython, and know the basics of C/C++ compilation.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

There is a decently large library written in C that I want to incorporate in my Python program. (In particular, it's the implementation of board logic for GNUGo. I'm experimenting with building AIs for it.) I need this routine to be fast, and using a Python implementation of the logic has been too slow.

The Cython documentation says that I should create a `.pxd` file that lists method signatures that are defined extern from the `.h` files. I should then create a wrapper class in the corresponding `.pyx` file, and manually create Python-side function calls that hook into the method signatures listed above.

The issue I have is that the library I want to implement isn't a single C file like the documentation example. It uses multiple C files, with their own interdependencies, and the game board is represented as a set of global variables that are defined extern all over the place. I really, really don't want to write `.pxd`s for all the required C files.

The GNUGo documentation suggests that I can create a `libboard.a` file - is this conceptually different from a `.o` file, and is there a way to include this file into Cython? I ideally want to treat it as a blackbox that lets me do a method call, have the library deal with its crazy global variable nuttiness, and return the desired output.

Comment: libboard.a is a library, whereas .o is an object file. Library can consist of many object files. Creating it makes sense, because a library can provide access to all the implementations of these functions.

Comment: `.a` is for "archive" --- the `ar` program in Unix.  (If you're on a Unix-like system, you probably have it.  Try `man ar`.)  It is the ancient precursor of `tar` ("tape archive"), `jar` ("Java archive"), and others.  It's just a bunch of files slapped together, with a simple index so you can find them again.  It's not specific to C programming... although I doubt you'll find anyone archiving files in `.a` for any other reason these days.  When you link `.o` files into a C executable, those `.o` files can be sitting in the directory, or inside a `.a` archive, or some of each.

Comment: You might find SWIG the better tool for the job. I believe it can scan headers files and automatically generate the stuff you need, where as with Cython you really will have to do it all by hand. I've never used SWIG though, so it could be bad advice...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the "proper" way to do it, but here's how I got it working.

In my `go.pxd` file, I list all method declarations I need from the header file `board.h`. Instead of doing

```
cdef extern from "board.h":
    ...
```

I do

```
cdef extern:
    ...
```

since I don't want to actually include the board.h file - I have the library `libboard.a` instead. Inside that block I list all the methods I need.

In my `go.pyx` file, I do `cimport go`, then do `go.method_name(args)` whenever I need to use it. Running Cython on `go.pyx` to generate `go.c` works file because all the methods are defined `extern`.

Finally, to turn it into a `go.so` library to import, I have a Makefile that basically does

```
gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing \
  -I/usr/include/python2.7 go.c libboard.a -o go.so
```

And the final `go.so` is importable in Python and works fine.

The tricky part was that I needed to recompile `libboard.a` with `-fPIC` before linking it. I also needed to remove some library calls to curses.h/term.h since I wasn't able to get those includes to work, but luckily I didn't need the pretty-printing anyways.

In general, it seems like you should be able to link arbitrary `.o` or `.a` declarations in the final step, as long as you don't specify where they are `extern` from in the `.pxd` file. That seems like it could get very messy very fast, but at least it works.

Comment: Yes, you're right - you only list the subset of functions you need from the library. Unless you've got good reason not to I'd still do "cdef extern from ..." - it's usually safer (more reliable type checking) and shouldn't cause problems. Have a look at http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html (the distutils section). You may find it makes building your library easier, but your makefile is fine too.